# Finding x coordinate of centre of gravity of solid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Solid is lying inside cylinder $x^2+y^2=2ax$, between planes z=0 and paraboloid $x^2+y^2=az$.

I can solve the triple integral but I don't know what is formula for finding x coordinate of C.O.G. Can you help with formulas relating to C.O.G

Comment: x coordinate is 1/v * ∫xm dx, where m is the size of the cross section taken from the yz plane

Comment: y coordinate is 1/v ∫ym dy where m is size of cross section taken from the xz plane, etc..